# android listview not working

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i am new to android development, and i just learnt about list views and array adapters etc. I have a project in android studio that has multiple activities and in one i have a array adapter and a list view, but every time i run the app and switch to the activity that has the list view in it the app does not respond and it closes. I have checked the code and it is the same as the code in the several tutorials i have seen. I think that it has something to do with the multiple activities i have, can someone help me?

```
public class StoreActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String[] storeList = {"Ship 1", "Ship 2", "Ship 3"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

    ListView store;
    store = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, storeList);
    store.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: check ur logs that will give u idea

Comment: Can you post the exception from the logcat?

Comment: Also let us see associated XML layouts in case logcat is not enough.

Comment: sorry i cant post the errors from the logcat its 5000 characters long :l  (sorry if i sound like a moron)

Comment: Post only the messages with level "E" (error) the red ones :)

Comment: the errors are around 5000 characters, the whole thing 9000

Comment: see my aswer, you need to add the id of the textview were you are going to display the values defined in the Array... ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.myTextView, storeList)

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsing an ArrayAdapter this is the correct way to initialize it:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, storeList);
```

for example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

    ListView store;
    store = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, storeList);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, storeList);
    store.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

#### but supossing that you want to load data inside your custom row layout (`row_layout.xml`), add the id of the textView (i think this is what you need) :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

    ListView store;
    store = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, storeList);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.row_layout,  R.id.myTextView, storeList);
    store.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, storeList);
```

to this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.TextViewofRow_layoutstoreList, storeList);
```

You need to say in which textview you will put your data.